# Cannot find media query rules in CSS file opened by python cssutils package

Tags: python, css

I need to modify the CSS rendering style for several similar web pages, so I'd intend to open each css file and modify their rules.

I tried to modify an element in web page, making it not disappear along with the change of screen size, the origin css rule is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px):
.base-header .group-list.nav {
display: none; }
```

I want to disable the `display: none` settings to make the element remain appearing.

Now I'd parse the first css file via cssutils:

```
import csutils

stylesheet = cssutils.parseFile('global.css')
```

In `stylesheet.cssRules`, I couldn't find the `display: none` rule setting under `@media screen` . However I could find other rule settings that is not under media query.

If I open the css file by `open()`, I could see the media query settings, but the file return by `open()` is more messy and seems hard to edit to me.

How could I find the rules under media query in css files?
Or is there better way to solve my problem, without using parsing method in cssutils?

Thank you for every advice!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I'm able to edit the file via traditional `open()` then edit file method.

If I use Visual Studio Code to open the css file then auto-format it, I could open the resulting file then edit it line-by-line.

However, for the css file I need to first format it to read the file line by line, otherwise the css file is too messy to parse. I still haven't find a way to solve this, BeatifulSoup seems not helping for CSS parsing problem.